# Save file with bulk action in to document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, save, local-storage

I am trying to save files in a document directory, in a bulk action and I am using this method:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/storage/image.png"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *downloadFolder = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
[data writeToFile:downloadFolder atomically:TRUE];
```

This is working well, but for a single file, I would like to copy in the same times all files in a STORAGE folder in a document directory.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to save the image bulk in your document directory. 
You can use **NSUserDefaults** to hold the last image index, and increment the index by one when you store a new image, try this.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/storage/image.png"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *filePath;

id index = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"imageIndex"];

if(index){
    int i = [((NSNumber *) index) intValue];
    i ++;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"imageIndex"];
    filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d.png",i]];

}else{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"imageIndex"];
    filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image_0.png"];
}

[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it working only with same file and continue to download and rename same image

Comment: yes because you have given only one file url, NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/storage/image.png"];

Comment: ok but if i give absolute link in folder without single file dosent work URLWithString:@"mywebsite.com/storage/"]